# Как найти проект на github.com по адресу электронной почты?

Tags: email, github, доступ

Вместо ссылки на репозиторий на github.com мне дают адрес электронной почты и какую-то комбинацию из цифр и букв, называя это данными для доступа к проекту. Как применить эти "данные", т.е. куда нужно вводить e-mail и этот код, чтобы зайти в репозиторий?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Войдите](https://github.com/login) на сайт github.com используя эти email/пароль, увидите репозитории

Comment: не получается. "неверно введен логин или пароль", да и пароль странный на 3 символа, а должно быть минимум 7

Comment: а предыдущий адрес и пароль совпали. спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

А это был точно адрес электронной почты? Или SSH линка с логином пользователя?
Последнее выглядит так: `git@github.com:tensorflow/tensorflow.git`

Чтобы попасть на страницу, надо убрать часть до `@`, заменить `:` на `/` и убрать `.git` *(необязательно)*.

Comment: да нет, прислали NNN@mail.ru, и потом комбинацию из цифр